# How to set Background Image of Root Layout in wp8 from App.XAML

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am using `App.Resources` to set Background Image of my Grid Layout in all my wp8 pages. I am stack in an issue where user can select one of the three backgrounds. I don't know how to make this through App.XAML. I have designed the interface that user can select one of these backgrounds, but don't know how to activate the selected.

Here is my APP.XAML

```
<Application.Resources>
 <Color x:Key="PageTitleForgroundColor">#000000</Color>
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PageTitleForegroundBrush" 
               Color="{StaticResource PageTitleForgroundColor}"/>

 <ImageBrush x:Key="AppBackgroundImage" ImageSource="/Assets/Background.jpg" 
               Stretch="UniformToFill"></ImageBrush>
 <ImageBrush x:Key="AppBackgroundImage_1" ImageSource="/Assets/Background.jpg" 
               Stretch="UniformToFill"></ImageBrush>
 <ImageBrush x:Key="AppBackgroundImage_2" ImageSource="/Assets/Background.jpg" 
               Stretch="UniformToFill"></ImageBrush>

 <!-- Grid Layout Background-->
 <Style x:Key="LayoutRootStyle" TargetType="Panel">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource AppBackgroundImage}"></Setter>
 </Style>

</Application.Resources>
```

As you can see I am setting the `Background` property in APP.XAML, How can I make it dynamic (It should be AppBackgroundImage_2, AppBackgroundImage_1 and AppBackgroundImage) based on user selection.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are trying to change this background in a Panorama control.
Panorama control (and I think Pivot controls as well) has some problem supporting late binding.

To dynamically change background images you should follow these steps;

- Create a Property (MainBackGroundImage) within your associated ViewModel, that implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface (if you are using MVVM pattern you already have this infrastructure).
- Assign any image path (this can be a remote URL as well) to this property whenever you want to change the background image.
- In your View hook up to your ViewModel's property changed event  and update the layout of the control where background image is going to appear:

  ```
   void viewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender,PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {

      if (e.PropertyName == “MainBackGroundImage”)
      {
            this.MainPanorama.UpdateLayout();
      }
      }
  ```

Comment: Thanks, I found this post [link](http://www.reflectionit.nl/Blog/2012/windows-8-xaml-tips-app-background-image) stating change `Frame` background, but don't know would be proper way to do it?

Comment: Yes but here the background image is being hard-coded. Instead of using a binding path if you also hard-code the background image path - you will also be able to display a static image. If you want to dynamically change the image you should follow the steps I described above.

Comment: Alternatively you can take a look at my Open-Source WP8 project where I do such stuff like changing the background image dynamically:

https://phoneguitartab.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

**The best way to do this would be to use your view model and give access to your configuration and use straight up binding there to do this.** The biggest problem stems from the fact that content of styles cannot be changed once you use them - on most platforms you will get an access denied exception.

If you are hell bent on using resources, this is what I came up with. There are probably easier ways of doing this...

1. Create a class called ObjectHolder. You will instantiate that in your resources model.

   public class ObjectHolder : DependencyObject
   {
       public object HeldObject
       {
           get { return (object)GetValue(HeldObjectProperty); }
           set { SetValue(HeldObjectProperty, value); }
       }

   ```
   // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HeldObject.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
   public static readonly DependencyProperty HeldObjectProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("HeldObject", typeof(object), typeof(ObjectHolder), new PropertyMetadata(null));
   ```

   }
2. In your app XAML, instantiate this. You will need 2 styles - one for each background as well (I am using solid color brushes for backgrounds since it was easier to test)..

   ```
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBackgroundImage1" Color="Blue" />
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBackgroundImage2" Color="Red" />

   <!-- Grid Layout Background-->
   <Style x:Key="LayoutRootStyle1" TargetType="Panel">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource AppBackgroundImage1}"></Setter>
   </Style>
   <Style x:Key="LayoutRootStyle2" TargetType="Panel">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource AppBackgroundImage2}"></Setter>
   </Style>
   <local:ObjectHolder x:Key="holder" HeldObject="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle1}"></local:ObjectHolder>
   ```
3. In your page XAML, bind to the held object instead of directly to a style:
4. In code, when switching styles, do the following (your code will actually be a little more complex - I just change from one to the other):

   ```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {

       var holder = (ObjectHolder)App.Current.Resources["holder"];
       holder.HeldObject = App.Current.Resources["LayoutRootStyle2"];
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, Do I need to do this in every page? I only want to sit it once and that should be used all over my application.

Comment: This works for me, I added this code in App.xaml.cs `RootFrame.Background = (System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush)App.Current.Resources["AppBackgroundImage_1"];` I am searching to do it using MVVM. appreciate your cooperation to do it using MVVM.